# Request for a Quick Call to Learn about Current Pain points on Ordinal and Altcoins

Tags: altcoin, ordinals

I am an MBA student at Kellogg School of Management. I am currently doing a project on bitcoin ordinal and inscription of altcoins. If you would be kind enough to squeeze in just a 5-15 minutes call, I would love to learn from you especially on the current pain point that you are facing. I believe that it would help me to learn more about the inscription of both bitcoin ordinal and altcoins.

Comment: I’m voting to close this topic because it is not a question, but a call for volunteers.